# CASE WHEN with two conditions on different tables

Tags: sql

I have two conditions in my CASE WHEN statement based on columns in two different tables :

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Destcf.dclibd = '' AND Scecol.ecnrun >= 500 THEN 'PRO'
     WHEN Destcf.dclibd = '' AND Scecol.ecnrun < 500 THEN 'RTC' 
     ELSE Destcf.dclibd
END, 
SUM(dcqtan) AS qte
FROM Scdcol
INNER JOIN Scecol ON Dceean = Eceean
LEFT JOIN Sccmdf ON Ecnrun = CFNRUN AND Ecnlot = CFNLOT
LEFT JOIN Destcf ON LEFT(CFREFC,2) = Dcndes
GROUP BY dclibd
```

I have an error saying "Column ECNRUN in SELECT is incorrect"

Do you have an idea how I can do this kind of query without using a UNION ?

Comment: GROUP BY happens *before* SELECT. You can't group by a calculated column from your SELECT clause.

Comment: I would try to make the join of the table in a cte then the case statement in the second part of the query (something like `with cte as (SELECT Destcf.dclibd, Scecol.ecnrun, dcqtan your_select_joining_all_tables) select CASE ... END, sum(..) from cte` - I hope you see what I mean)

Comment: Austin I edited the question and removed group by. 
Tomalak It works great if my second condition is another column of Destcf table.
Christophe will try this ! I think it works the same way as Farshid answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a select over your queries and use group by in outer select. Your query will be in this way:

```
select typ_flux, SUM(dcqtan) AS qte
from (
   SELECT 
     CASE WHEN Destcf.dclibd = '' AND Scecol.ecnrun >= 500 THEN 'PRO'
          WHEN Destcf.dclibd = '' AND Scecol.ecnrun < 500 THEN 'RTC' 
          ELSE Destcf.dclibd
     END AS typ_flux, 
     dcqtan 
   FROM Scdcol
   INNER JOIN Scecol ON Dceean = Eceean
   LEFT JOIN Sccmdf ON Ecnrun = CFNRUN AND Ecnlot = CFNLOT
   LEFT JOIN Destcf ON LEFT(CFREFC,2) = Dcndes
)t
GROUP BY typ_flux
```

Comment: This works ! Thanks. Why do I have to surround my query ? If I don't add the second condition (AND Scecol.ecnrun >=500 / AND Scecol.ecnrun < 500) in the query I posted, it worked great.

Comment: @WaLinke cause of produce the result in a subquery then use it in the outer select Group by expression. yeah, when you remove them it works but does not meet your requirements.